# Library development/debug with Maven

Tags: maven

I am in the processing of integrating Maven into my my projects. While maven has plenty of pros i'm finding it difficult to figure out how to maintain my current development process, which is as follows:

For creating SDKs I will create a sample app, which will depend on and directly reference the SDK source code, all from within the same code project. This means that I can make easily change/debug the SDK code with one click run/debugging.

I fear this won't really be possible with Maven. Can I create some type of Hybrid approach, where I continue my normal development approach and then push builds to Maven when it is appropriate.

**Update - For Clarity**

My problem is that when everything is done through maven, the dependencies are built and published to Maven. Then, the dependent project pulls down compiled references and uses them. My issues is that I don't want to go through this whole process every time I make a small change to a dependency.Thanks.

Comment: Are you using modules? You can have a project with several modules, one the SDK, the other the sample app.

Comment: Yes, they are distinct modules.

Comment: I think I'm not really understanding your question/problem, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating parent level `pom.xml` with two modules - your library and simple app to test it. In simple app's  `pom.xml` provide a dependency on library module.

Then open in your IDE parent pom as maven project. This should be sufficient for normal debug.

Other possible approach - install you library artifact into maven repo with sources. In this case you will be able to debug it, but test app still have to load use jars from repo.